# How to solve ode with convolution?

Tags: differential-equations, integral-equations, convolution, version-7

my question is as this and i want to get the solution of this ode `x(t)`

$
({M_{33}}{\rm{ + }}{{\rm{m}}_{33}})x''(t) + \int\limits_{ - \infty }^t {x'(tau){K_{33}}(t - tau)d{\rm{ }}tau}  = {F_3}(t)\\
{K_{33}}(t) = \frac{2}{\pi }\int\limits_0^{ + \infty } {{b_{33}}} (\omega )\cos (\omega t)d\omega \\
$

and the defined value is as this

${F_3}(t)= 31.4380978232711cos(3.9893240045584673t);\\
 M_{33} = 1.95;\\
 m_{33} = 2.5;$

codes asre as this

```
b33 = 2.52077405993092/(46.4663900509659 + omega^2 - 
11.8316929905336*omega);
k33 = 2/\[Pi]*Integrate[b33*Cos[omega*t], {omega, 0, +\[Infinity]}]

(*1.60477 If[
  t \[Element] 
   Reals, (0.0190724 - 
  0.0333163 I) ((3.33766 - 
     1.91069 I) Cosh[(3.38661 + 5.91585 I) Abs[
      t]] CosIntegral[(-5.91585 + 3.38661 I) Abs[
      t]] - (0.955346 + 
     1.66883 I) Sinh[(3.38661 + 5.91585 I) Abs[t]] (\[Pi] - 
     2. SinIntegral[(-5.91585 + 3.38661 I) Abs[
         t]])) + (0.0190724 + 
  0.0333163 I) ((3.33766 + 
     1.91069 I) Cos[(5.91585 + 3.38661 I) Abs[
      t]] CosIntegral[(-5.91585 - 3.38661 I) Abs[t]] + (1.66883 + 
     0.955346 I) Sin[(5.91585 + 3.38661 I) Abs[t]] (\[Pi] + 
     2 SinIntegral[(5.91585 + 3.38661 I) Abs[t]])), 
  Integrate[Cos[omega t]/(
   46.4664 - 11.8317 omega + omega^2), {omega, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
   Assumptions -> t \[NotElement] Reals]]*)
```

**int2 = Integrate[x'[tau]*k33[t - tau], {tau, -[Infinity], t}]**

it is **x'[tau]** rather than **x'[t]**

```
ft = 31.4380978232711` Cos[3.9893240045584673` t];
M33 = 1.95;
m33 = 2.5;


equation = (M33 + m33)*x''[t] + int2 == ft;
ts = 50;

s1 = NDSolve[{equation, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, ts}]
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. s], {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```

however it doesn't work so how to solve it?

**updated3**

now i use `fit` method to get the `b33` and we can use this `b33` to get the `k33` but it seems that this `k33` figure is queer from t=0-100`.

`k33` in some essay is as this
[image]

**updated4**

now the question changes to this ,how to solve the integral equation

```
k33[t_] := 
  20*(-1.01880661301011*
 Sin[-12.2868520317448*t]/(12.3729623105373*t + 
    31.6231386532942*t^2));

int2 = Integrate[x'[tau]*k33[t - tau], {tau, -\[Infinity], t}];

ft = 31.4380978232711` Cos[3.9893240045584673` t];
M33 = 1.95;
m33 = 2.5;

equation = (M33 + m33)*x''[t] + int2 == ft;
ts = 50;

s1 = NDSolve[{equation, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, ts}]
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. s1], {t, 0, ts}]
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102159/discussion-between-dcydhb-and-xzczd).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem doesn't lie in _Mathematica_ side, it's because the $B_z$ used by OP doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102198/discussion-on-question-by-dcydhb-how-to-solve-ode-with-convolution).